# Fill available space in tabular square

Tags: tables

I am trying to have the inner text of each square of my `\tabular` fill the whole space available. For example, in the tabular below, I would like my a2 and b2 occupy the entire `column` under s2 in a way to not reveal clear empty spaces where would be c2 and d2.

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}

...

\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\bf title}\\
  \hline \hline
  \bf s1 & \bf s2 & \bf s3 & \bf s4\\
  \hline \hline
  \multirow{4}{*}{$\varnothing$} & a2 & a3 & a4\\
  & b2 & b3 & b4\\
  & & c3 & c4\\
  & & d3 &\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\label{table}\end{center}
```

Would anyone have a clue, please?

---

Edit:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}

...

\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\bf Requête}\\
  \hline \hline
  \bf s1 & \bf s2 & \bf s3 & \bf s4\\
  \hline \hline
  \multirow{5}{*}{$\varnothing$} & \multirow{2}{*}{a2} & a3 & \multirow{3}{*}{a4}\\
  & \multirow{2}{*}{b2} & b3 & \multirow{3}{*}{b4}\\
  & & c3 & \multirow{3}{*}{c4}\\
  & & d3 &\\
  & & e3 &\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\end{center}
```

After Ignasi post, I popularized to the entire table. But a malfunction appears under 's2': [image: Table]

Comment: I've updated the answer for five rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\multirow` and some spacing hacks to get this result (see first table below), but without knowing more about your data it's hard to see how this would help the reader.

It might be clearer to rotate your table, as in the second example below, which also uses the `booktabs` package for (arguably) more attractive table formatting.

---

Note that `\bf` is a deprecated command; use `\textbf{}` instead. Even better, as I show here, is to define a semantic command like `\tableheader` to separate style from content. There are table packages that will make that even easier.

I would also suggest using a table caption instead of a title row, and using `etoolbox` to center all the tables.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow} % for \multirow
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \varnothing
\usepackage[position=above]{caption} % for table caption positioned above

\usepackage{booktabs} % for more attractive table spacing and rules
\usepackage{etoolbox} % center the tables
\AtEndEnvironment{table}{\centering}

\newcommand{\tableheader}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Title}
\label{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
%\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\tableheader{title}}\\ % use caption instead?
%\hline \hline
\tableheader{s1} & \tableheader{s2} & \tableheader{s3} & \tableheader{s4}\\
\hline \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{$\varnothing$} & 
    \multirow{4}{*}{%
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c}
        a2\\
        b2\\
        \end{tabular}%
        \vspace*{\fill}%
    } & a3 & a4\\
 & & b3 & b4\\
 & & c3 & c4\\
 & & d3 &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

%***************************************
\begin{table}
\caption{Rotated}
\label{table:rotated}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}c}
\toprule
S-value & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Result}\\
\midrule
s1      & $\varnothing$ & $\varnothing$ & $\varnothing$ & $\varnothing$\\
s2      & a2 & b2 & &\\
s3      & a3 & b3 & c3 & d3\\
s4      & a4 & b4 & c4 & d4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In the future please post a full example including all packages used (in this case `multirow` and `amssymb`).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post to show an unexpected feature that seems to appear in your code too: my s2 column is not well spread.

Comment: I found the answer. I just moved my s2 `multicolumn` content one `row` down, and the texts are correctly placed.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure to understand the question, but something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\bf title}\\
  \hline \hline
  \bf s1 & \bf s2 & \bf s3 & \bf s4\\
  \hline \hline
  \multirow{4}{*}{$\varnothing$} & \multirow{2}{*}{a2} & a3 & a4\\
  & & b3 & b4\\
  & \multirow{2}{*}{b2} & c3 & c4\\
  & & d3 &\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\label{table}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Proposed solution needs to be adjusted with any new row which is added to the original table. In case it's extended to five rows, `multirow` could be only applied to fourth column while second column is composed for misplaced regular cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\bf title}\\
  \hline \hline
  \bf s1 & \bf s2 & \bf s3 & \bf s4\\
  \hline \hline
  \multirow{5}{*}{$\varnothing$} &  & a3 & \multirow{2}{*}{a4}\\
  & a2 & b3 & \\
  & & c3 & b4\\
  & b2 & d3 &\multirow{2}{*}{c4}\\
  & & e3 &\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\label{table}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]